# Transaction propagation SUPPORTS leads to "HHH000326: Cannot join transaction" warning

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions, spring-transactions

We are using JPA (Hibernate 4) with Spring 4 managing the JTA transactions. To allow lazy initialization even when simply reading from the database without any transaction we added the "OpenEntityManager" pattern.

However with this pattern active, Spring tries to join the already open entity manager to a SUPPORTS transaction as well (`EntityManagerFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalEntityManager`). Hibernate however denies this request with a (somehow misleading) warning:

```
WARN: HHH000326: Cannot join transaction: do not override hibernate.transaction.factory_class
```

I think that `joinTransaction()` should only be called if `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()`?

You can find a test case for these questions on GitHub https://github.com/abenneke/sandbox/tree/master/spring-hibernate4-transaction

Thank you!

(We now worked around this warning by simply adding another EntityManagerProxy skipping any `joinTransaction()` request if there is no actual transaction active.)

Update July 2015:
I now created an improvement request for this one:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13242

Answer (score 0):

HHH000326 "It was actually a problem of our Software at some place we called EntityManager.joinTransaction(), which is not required anymore in Hibernate 4.1."
check this as the same question: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2455341&

Comment: Thank you for the insight into your Software - however it was a bug in Spring in my case which is fixed since Spring 4.2.

Comment: Sorry to mention that I just copy the words which is showed in the web the link linked. And I  use Spring 4.1(cry).