# How to configure MySQL JTA resource in Spring, JPA and Hibernate for Glassfish v3?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, jta

My application is able to perform the read operations but unable to write to the database. How should I configure the JTA transaction manager? I'm using the following: Glassfish 3.1.2.2, Hibernate 4.2.21, Spring 4.2.5, MySQL 5.6 and JDK 1.6. I've tried the following configuration:

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="appPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/app</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
    <!--<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"-->
    <!--value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory"/>-->
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

web.xml

```xml
<persistence-unit-ref>
    <persistence-unit-ref-name>persistence/appPersistenceUnit</persistence-unit-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>appPersistenceUnit</persistence-unit-name>
</persistence-unit-ref>
```

applicationContext.xml

```xml
<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" 
                 jndi-name="persistence/appPersistenceUnit"/>
<tx:jta-transaction-manager/>
<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

MyDAOImpl.java

```java
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED, name = "appPersistenceUnit")
protected EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public int save(final MyEntity myEntity) {
    try {
        entityManager.merge(myEntity);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error while saving MyEntity", e);
    }
    return 1; // id of the created element.
}
```

On trying to save the entity, I get the following error:

```
Cannot join transaction: do not override hibernate.transaction.factory_class
```

Please guide me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to remove your `hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class` property from your persistence.xml

Comment: @Jaumzera I added it yesterday after reading an article/question. I've removed it and still facing the same issue. Do I even need to use a JTA transaction manager? I read somewhere that JTA- allows
for distributed transactions across multiple datasources. I don't have any such requirement. Just because we have glassfish and the datasource is referred using JNDI, I used the jta transaction manager.

Comment: I'm not sure about how Spring handles transactions, but using JTA means that you leave the container take care of the TX management. The most part of time, I've seen people using Spring with RESOURCE_LOCAL transactions and a lightweight container such as Tomcat or Jetty. Backing to your question, considering `Cannot join transaction: do not override hibernate.transaction.factory_class`, it seems you have an implementation missing.

Comment: There's a similar problem in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345538/transaction-propagation-supports-leads-to-hhh000326-cannot-join-transaction-w

It's the same error, at least. Check it out, plese. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Jaumzera I had already seen this link and a couple other about the JTA transaction manager before posting the question. They mention about the version upgrade, I already did that. Please see the commented properties of the persistence unit. I've tried all of them. The error message changes but the problem remains the same. I've also tried the Extended transaction in the PersistenceContext annotation. None of it works.